# How to print all package HTTP

Tags: java, linux, server

a just want to print all packages like bellow. Its simple HTTP analyzer java code. Please check out my main. How i can print protocol name or other function. Thank you

```
//package jdumper.analyzer;
import jpcap.packet.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;



public class HTTPAnalyzer extends JDPacketAnalyzer
{

private static HTTPAnalyzer analy;

public static void main(String arg[] )
{
    System.out.println(boom.getValueNames());;
}

private static final String[] valueNames={
    "Method",
    "Header"
};

String method;

Vector headers=new Vector();

public HTTPAnalyzer(){
    layer=APPLICATION_LAYER;
}

public boolean isAnalyzable(Packet p){
    if(p instanceof TCPPacket &&
       (((TCPPacket)p).src_port==80 || ((TCPPacket)p).dst_port==80))
        return true;
    else return false;
}



public String getProtocolName(){
    return "HTTP";
}

public String[] getValueNames(){
    return valueNames;
}

public void analyze(Packet p){
    method="";
    headers.removeAllElements();

    if(!isAnalyzable(p)) return;

    try{
        BufferedReader in=new BufferedReader(new StringReader(new String(p.data)));

        method=in.readLine();

        if(method==null || method.indexOf("HTTP")==-1){

            // this packet doesn't contain HTTP header
            method="Not HTTP Header";

            return;
        }


        String l;

        //read headers

        while((l=in.readLine()).length()>0)

            headers.addElement(l);

    }catch(IOException e){}

}



public Object getValue(String valueName){

    if(valueNames[0].equals(valueName)) return method;

    if(valueNames[1].equals(valueName)) return headers;

    return null;

}



Object getValueAt(int index){

    if(index==0) return method;

    if(index==1) return headers;

    return null;

}



public Object[] getValues(){

    Object[] values=new Object[2];

    values[0]=method;

    values[1]=headers;



    return values;

}

}
```

Comment: I suppose from the class you're extending that you're using jpcap from http://jpcap.sourceforge.net/ . If that's the case, please be more specific about what do you need to be printed.

Comment: Thank you answer my question. Can you show me how i can print HTTP all packages

Comment: I would be happy to but I need to understand what do you mean by "package". Do you mean Headers? Response Body? Full text of the packet?

Comment: Yes, i mean HTTP Headers

Answer (score 1):

Here's the problem.  HTTP is a stream based protocol - it runs over a TCP/IP stream.  In order to accurately parse / extract the headers an HTTP stream you first need to reassemble the stream from the packets.  Once you have done that (accurately) you can then parse the stream and extract the headers.  However, if you simply look at the individual packets in a HTTP stream, you can't reliably tell which ones contain headers, and which ones are part of the HTTP request or response body.

---

Ignoring that issue, I'm having difficulty figuring out what version of jpcap / jpcap / jdumper / whatever you class is supposed to be built against.  That makes it difficult to figure out how a subclass of `JDPacketAnalyzer` is supposed to be used.  But I'm pretty sure that it is NOT supposed to have a `main` method.

Comment: If i want to print all captured packeges in terminal in Linux. How i can do this ?

Comment: Install tcpdump or wireshark or similar.  This is NOT a programming problem.